# X Y Plot with R

Tags: r, plot, coordinates

I have this data

```
             X,           Y,      ag
   4068961.415,  731027.852,  1.5000
   4068962.701,  731027.829,  0.9500
   4068963.986,  731027.807,  2.5000
   4068965.271,  731027.784,  2.5000
   4068875.402,  730996.864,  3.9000
   4068875.402,  730996.864,  3.0796
   4068875.402,  730996.864,  1.6060
   4068910.645,  731067.069,  0.6400
```

Want a reproducible example ? copy this data and do  `d <- read.csv("clipboard")`

How can I get a kind of map plotting the column named `ag`, depending on its coordinate ?

I want

- `X column` at the x axis
- `Y column` at Y axis
- depending on `ag` value, the color of the plotted point changes (from yellow to red).

Comment: +1 for `d <- read.csv("clipboard")`

Comment: Please note that `read.csv("clipboard")` does not work on every platform.

Comment: But it works well on Windows and OSX. which other platform it does not work???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, you can use something like this:

```
with(d, plot(X, Y, col=rainbow(n=length(ag),start=0, end=1/6)[order(ag)], pch=19))
```

Comment: yes.. notice the first `x` in your answer represent `d` in my question.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with library `ggplot2`. 
For changing of color scale use `scale_color_gradient()`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d,aes(X,Y,color=ag))+geom_point()+
        scale_color_gradient(low="yellow",high="red")
```

Comment: Is there a way to create colors based on the range of `ag`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've tried: `with(d,plot(Y~X,col=ag))`?